# Update single key in realm into array of model in array of model

Tags: ios, swift, model, realm, objectmapper

I am facing on problem, I want to update a single key in my realm model which is in below hierarchy.

```
Array Model -> Array Model - Key

class OrdersOfDeliveryModel: Object, Mappable {

dynamic var id : String?
dynamic var transportCost : String?

var items = List<ItemsModel>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id                  <- map["id"]
        transportCost       <- map["transportCost"]
        items               <- (map["items"], ListTransform<ItemsModel>())
    }
}

class ItemsModel : Object, Mappable{

dynamic var orderedQty  : Int = 0
dynamic var orderedReceivedQty  : String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return nil
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        var dictWeightageqty = [String:Any]()
        dictWeightageqty     <- map["weightageQty"]
        orderedQty          = dictWeightageqty["ordered"] as? Int ?? 0
        orderedReceivedQty  = dictWeightageqty["received"] as? String
    }
}
```

Please consider this example.

I want to update `orderedReceivedQty` key which is in `ItemsModel` but How can I find that key in realm. But my `ItemsModel` is depending on `OrderOfDeliveryModel` which can I find with primary key.

I have ways like I delete this whole model using single ID and replace it with new data OR I can get that key and update it.

I dont want to delete whole object and insert new I want to update single key.

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `OrderOfDeliveryModel` object, you can query it for the `ItemsModel` object you want to update, and then update it in place (if you find it).

```
let results = myOrders.items.filter("orderedQty == %@", 10)
if (results.count == 1) {
    results[0].orderedReceivedQty = 10
}
```

Comment: if I have 10 items and same orderedQty so this is wrong solutions

Comment: It was just an example. You can filter based on any property that uniquely identifies the object you are looking for,